# changing a boolean value between multiple classes

Tags: java, eclipse, class, object, boolean

So, my assignment is to make multiple "animal" classes and run them on a blank drawing panel. Each animal moves in a specific way and when they overlap with a different animal, the "invading" animal wins while the other animal is removed. My teacher told me to use a boolean that would return true (animal dies) if two animals crossed on the same coordinates and returned false on all other occasions.

I set a boolean method "isSameLoc()" on the Animal class that automatically returns false, but I don't know how to switch the value to true when animals overlap in the main client class. Any kind of advice is appreciated.

I also apologize in advance as I'm about to post 6 different classes on here so this will get kind of long. I don't know if there's an easier way to do this so, again, I'm sorry.

Animal class:

```
import java.awt.Color; 

import java.awt.Point;


public abstract class Animal {
private String type;
public Animal(String type, String name, Point location, Color color) {
    super();
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.color = color;
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}
public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}
private String name;
private Point location;
private Color color;
private boolean sameLoc = false;

public boolean isSameLoc() {

    return sameLoc;
}

public abstract String toString();
public abstract void move ();
public Point getLocation() {
    return location;
}
public void setLocation(Point location) {
    this.location = location;
}


}
```

AnimalSimulator:

```
import java.awt.Color;   
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;


public class AnimalSimulator {




public static void main(String[] args) {

        DrawingPanel forest = new DrawingPanel(720, 640);
        Graphics2D pen = forest.getGraphics();
        Animal [] animals = new Animal[15];

        for (int i = 0; i < animals.length;i++){

            int selection = (int) (Math.random()*4+1);
            int randX = (int) (Math.random()*720+1);
            int randY = (int) (Math.random()*640+1);
            switch(selection){
            case 1:
                Bird b = new Bird ("Avian", "Birdie", new Point(randX, randY), Color.BLUE);
                animals[i] = b;
                break;
            case 2:
                Frog f = new Frog ("Amphibian", "Frogger", new Point(randX, randY), Color.GREEN);
                animals[i] = f;
                break;
            case 3:
                Mouse m = new Mouse ("Rodent", "Mickey", new Point(randX, randY), Color.DARK_GRAY);
                animals[i] = m;
                break;
            case 4:
                Rabbit r = new Rabbit ("Rodent", "Bugs", new Point(randX, randY), Color.ORANGE);
                animals[i] = r;
                break;
            //case 5:
                //Turtle t = new Turtle("Reptile", "Tortoise", new Point(randX, randY), Color.CYAN);
                //animals[i] = t;
                //break;
            //case 6:
                //Snake s = new Snake("Slither", "Kaa", new Point(randX,   randY), Color.RED);
                //animals[i] = s;
                //break;
            }
        }

        for (int time = 1; time <= 100; time++){
            for (int i = 0; i < animals.length; i++){       

                pen.setColor(animals[i].getColor());
                pen.drawString(animals[i].toString(),     animals[i].getLocation().x, animals[i].getLocation().y);

                animals[i].move();

                for (int a = 0; a< animals.length; a++){
                    boolean death = animals[i].isSameLoc();
                    if(a!= i){
                        if (animals[i].equals(animals[a])){
                            death = true;
                            if(death){
                                animals[a] = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    }
                }
                forest.sleep(50);
            }

        }






    }
```

Bird Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;  
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;

public class Bird extends Animal{


public Bird(String type, String name, Point location, Color color) {
    super(type, name, location, color);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public  String toString() {
    if (isSameLoc()){
        return null;
    }else{
        return "B";
    }

}

@Override
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see Animal#move()
 * this, I had no real problems with, just random directions but 
 * I think it was supposed to be alot more spread out.
 */
public void move() {
    int newX = getLocation().x+3;
    int negX = getLocation().x-3;
    int newY = getLocation().y+3;
    int negY = getLocation().y-3;
    int direct = (int) (Math.random()*4+1);

    if (direct == 1){
        setLocation(new Point(getLocation().x, newY));
    }else if (direct == 2){
        setLocation(new Point(getLocation().x, negY));
    }else if (direct == 3){
        setLocation(new Point(newX, getLocation().y));
    }else if (direct == 4){
        setLocation(new Point(negX, getLocation().y));
    }
}


}
```

frog class:

```
import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.Point;


public class Frog extends Animal {
private int steps = 0;

public Frog(String type, String name, Point location, Color color) {
    super(type, name, location, color);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public  String toString() {
    if (isSameLoc()){
        return null;
    }else{
        return "F";
    }

}
@Override
/*
 *For this, I couldn't tell if it was moving in the
 *right pattern. I knew it was moving randomly, but I 
 *don't think it was moving in the right increments.
 */
public void move() {
    int newX = getLocation().x+3;
    int negX = getLocation().x-3;
    int newY = getLocation().y+3;
    int negY = getLocation().y-3;
    int direct = (int) (Math.random()*4+1);

    if (steps < 3){
        if (direct == 1){
            setLocation(new Point(getLocation().x, newY));
        }else if (direct == 2){
            setLocation(new Point(getLocation().x, negY));
        }else if (direct == 3){
            setLocation(new Point(newX, getLocation().y));
        }else if (direct == 4){
            setLocation(new Point(negX, getLocation().y));
        }
        steps++;
    }
    if (steps >= 3){
        steps = 0;
    }


}

}
```

mouse class:

```
import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.Point;


public class Mouse extends Animal {

public Mouse(String type, String name, Point location, Color color) {
    super(type, name, location, color);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public  String toString() {
    if (isSameLoc()){
        return null;
    }else{
        return "M";
    }

}

@Override

public void move() {
    int newX = getLocation().x+3;
    int negX = getLocation().x-3;
    int newY = getLocation().y+3;
    int negY = getLocation().y-3;

    setLocation(new Point(negX, negY));
}

}
```

finally rabbit class:

```
import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.Point;


public class Rabbit extends Animal {
private int steps = 0;

public Rabbit(String type, String name, Point location, Color color) {
    super(type, name, location, color);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public  String toString() {
    if (isSameLoc()){
        return null;
    }else{
        return "R";
    }

}

@Override

public void move() {
    int newX = getLocation().x+3;
    int negX = getLocation().x-3;
    int newY = getLocation().y+3;
    int negY = getLocation().y-3;

    if (steps < 2){
        setLocation(new Point(getLocation().x, newY));
    }else if(steps < 4){
        setLocation(new Point(newX, getLocation().y));
    }else if(steps < 6){
        setLocation(new Point(getLocation().x, negY));
    }
    steps++;
    if(steps >= 6){
        steps = 0;
    }
}

}
```

there's actually more animal classes to this but I figured 4 was enough to get a test run done. Again, sorry for the long post. thank you.

Comment: This forum is not for slaving your assignments

Comment: They're hardly slaving their assignment, they're asking a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Issameloc requires two animals to do its job:

```
boolean death = animals[i].isSameLoc(animals[a]);
```

Comment: When I tried this, all the other animal class (bird, frog, etc) had to have their String methods altered to fit the new parameter. they wouldn't accept anything other than "null" though. like for bird; it would be "if(issameLoc(null)){... aside from that, nothing else about the program seemed to change when I run it

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve by having that call in the `ToString`?

Comment: when I first wrote it, I thought I wouldn't need to write anything in the AnimalSimulator class when it came to "death" amongst the other animals. I thought I could just write the boolean conditions in the Animal class and then just have the conditions for death in each individual animal but I guess it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not entirely sure how having animals[a] as a parameter would really change anything. So far, nothing appears to change when the animals overlap.

Comment: In order to see if an animal overlaps another, you need two animals. One is in `this`, the other must be passed in to `isSameLoc` as a parameter.

Comment: so I need to have one animal (animal[a]) be the parameter and i need to write "isSameLoc()" in such a way that it will compare the two animals and return true if they overlap. sort of like this: private boolean sameLoc;
 private Animal animals;
 public boolean isSameLoc(Animal animals) {
  if (this.animals == animals){
   return sameLoc = true;
  }else{
   return sameLoc = false;
  }
 }
 this code didn't really work either, but I want to know if I'm at least on the right track.